# Filter search based on array values in angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, search, ecmascript-6, key-value

I am new in angular 4. While trying to make a search bar got stuck in the logic. So I have a JSON file, and I am trying to search relevant key value pair of that JSON file based on an array values. 
My json file :

```
const trips = {
  "20180201": [{
      "journeyId": 1001,
      "Number": "001",
      "DriverName": "Alex",
      "Transporter": {
        "id": "T1",
        "number": "AN01001",
        "Company": "Tranzient"
      },
      "place": [{
          "id": 001,
          "value": "Washington DC"
        },
        {
          "id": 002,
          "value": "Canberra"
        }
      ],
    },
    {
      "journeyId": 1002,
      "Number": "001",
      "DriverName": "Tom",
      "Transporter": {
        "id": "T2",
        "number": "AN01002",
        "Company": "Trax"
      },
      "place": [{
          "id": 2,
          "value": "Canberra"
        },
        {
          "id": 4,
          "value": "Vienna"
        }
      ],
    },
    {
      "journeyId": 1003,
      "Number": "004",
      "DriverName": "Jack",
      "Transporter": {
        "id": "T3",
        "number": "AN01003",
        "Company": "Trax"
      },
      "place": [{
        "id": 1,
        "value": "Washington DC",
      }, {
        "id": 4,
        "value": "Vienna",
      }],
    }
  ],
  "20180211": [{
      "journeyId": 1004,
      "Number": "005",
      "DriverName": "Jack",
      "Transporter": {
        "id": "T3",
        "number": "AN01013",
        "Company": "Trax"
      },
      "place": [{
          "id": 5,
          "value": "Bridgetown"
        },
        {
          "id": 6,
          "value": "Ottawa"
        },
        {
          "id": 4,
          "value": "Boston"
        }
      ],

    },
    {
      "journeyId": 1005,
      "Number": "005",
      "DriverName": "Jerry",
      "Transporter": {
        "id": "T3",
        "number": "AN01020",
        "Company": "Trax"
      },
      "place": [{
          "id": 5,
          "value": "Bridgetown"
        },
        {
          "id": 6,
          "value": "Ottawa"
        }
      ],
    }
  ],
  "20180301": [{
    "journeyId": 1006,
    "Number": "005",
    "DriverName": "demy",
    "Transporter": {
      "id": "T3",
      "number": "AN01003",
      "Company": "Trax"
    },
    "place": [{
        "id": 5,
        "value": "Bridgetown"
      },
      {
        "id": 6,
        "value": "Vienna"
      }
    ],
  }],
};
```

I have an array

```
SelectedValues= ["20180201","Vienna"]
```

All the array values should search depending on the result from its previous array value. For example in this array above, I need to return key value pair of all the places which have its value "Vienna" in date "20180201".

expected output:

```
trips= {
  "20180201": [
  {
      "journeyId": 1002,
      "Number": "001",
      "DriverName": "Tom",
      "Transporter": {
        "id": "T2",
        "number": "AN01002",
        "Company": "Trax"
      },
      "place": [{
          "id": 2,
          "value": "Canberra"
        },
        {
          "id": 4,
          "value": "Vienna"
        }
      ],
    },
    {
      "journeyId": 1003,
      "Number": "004",
      "DriverName": "Jack",
      "Transporter": {
        "id": "T3",
        "number": "AN01003",
        "Company": "Trax"
      },
      "place": [{
        "id": 1,
        "value": "Washington DC",
      }, {
        "id": 4,
        "value": "Vienna",
      }],
    }
  ]

}
```

So the result returns all the key value pair that have place "Vienna" within the date " 20180201 " .

My solution that I tried to use :

```
filter(trips, SelectedValues) {
    const check = v => options.includes(v) || v && typeof v === 'object' && Object.keys(v).some(l => check(v[l]));
    var result = {};
    Object.keys(object).forEach(function (k) {
        var temp = options.includes(k)
            ? object[k]
            : object[k].filter(check);

        if (temp.length) {
            result[k] = temp;
        }
    });
    return result;
    }
```

The problem is that it is returning all the key-value pairs that matches all the values in SelectedValues(Implementing **OR** logic). But I need to implement the array search with **AND** logic.

Comment: I am not sure why you are trying to search in this fashion but I think its a bad design to search a data. You want to search data without knowing their `key` and structure. This will cause too many loops to execute & find the entry similar to values present in `SelectedValues` array.I hope you got my point.

Comment: @ShashankVivek I need to implement the filter search facility in my app.

Comment: Based on that if I have an array= ["20180201",coorg, AS01A0202], I need to check all the vehicle whose number is AS01A0202 in the place    "coorg" within the date range of 20180201. Can you suggest me a better way to do it

Comment: Great ques, here is the catch. How will our `search` function knows that **AS01A0202** is **vehicle number** ?? its you who knows, but the `search` function will search all the properties of all the arrays . Now what is **AS01A0202**  is entered as `place.value` ?? You'll get incorrect search result . Did you get the flaw ?

Comment: @ShashankVivek for "Now what is AS01A0202 is entered as place.value ?? " , it is taken care care while data input. AS01A0202 will never be inside a place.value.

Comment: but if I need that kind of searching facility can you suggest an alternate way?

Comment: requirement is like: if there is a date "20180201", search all the trips whose place is "Vienna" on that date than search the vehicle from all the result I get after searching Vienna.